# Setting width and length for image inside a table layout dynamically

Tags: java, android, user-interface, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I added a table-layout programatically in my app. The first column consists of imageviews and the second of textviews as in the code below

```
for (int i = 0; i <23; i++) {

            TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            row.setLayoutParams(lp);


            tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(array[i]);


            ImageView image65 = new ImageView(this);
            image65.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_no);


            row.addView(tv,1);
            row.addView(image65,0);
            ll.addView(row,i);
        }
```

Everything is good except that I want to specify the width and length of the image view in sp. How do I add layoutprams for the image view beside the layout-prams of the row? I tried the following but it didn't work out.

```
for (int i = 0; i <23; i++) {

                TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
                TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                row.setLayoutParams(lp);
                TableRow.LayoutParams lp2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(customwidth,customheight);


                tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(array[i]);


                ImageView image65 = new ImageView(this);
                image65.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_no);
                image65.setLayoutParams(lp2);


                row.addView(tv,1);
                row.addView(image65,0);
                ll.addView(row,i);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
for (int i = 0; i <23; i++) {

            TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            row.setLayoutParams(lp);


            tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(array[i]);


             ImageView image65 = new ImageView(this);
             Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_yes);
             image65.setImageDrawable(d);
             image65.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(40, 40));



            row.addView(tv,1);
            row.addView(image65,0);
            ll.addView(row,i);
        }
```